# Read string from bluetooth on Arduino Mega

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I am trying to read a string on a arduino mega using the bluetooth module HC-05. The modulo is connected to ports 18 and 19 (Serial1).

This is the function I wrote. It is supposed to receive `5588-#` and cut the incoming message when it gets the `#` character, but the output I'm getting is this string cut on random places (`58`, `588`, `8-`,`-`, etc.)

```
    static String getCommand() {
        // Serial1.listen();
        char character = 0;
        String command = "";

        while (Serial1.available() > 0) {
            character = Serial1.read();
            if (character != '#') {
                character = character & 0x7F;
                command += character;
            } else {
                // Serial.println("return");
                return command;
            }
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I didn't mean to. I don't know it was there, it had nothing to do with what I'm doing

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of time testing I realized that if I put a `delay(1000);` inside the `while` loop the code would run correctly.

This isn't the best solution but it works.